# How to handle nonmatches in stringr str_match_all in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to extract the second occurrence of a regex match in R using `str_match_all()` from the `stringr` package. I was able to make it work like this:

```
library(stringr)

string <- '"priceItems":[{"localizedTitle":"Fees","localizedExplanation":"Misc fee.","total":{"amount":3198,"amountFormatted":"$3,198","currency":"USD","__typename":"PriceTotal"},"type":"VILLA_FEE","__typename":"PriceItem"},{"localizedTitle":"Occupancy taxes and fees","localizedExplanation":"Tax","total":{"amount":8246,"amountFormatted":"$8,246","currency":"USD","__typename":"PriceTotal"},"type":"TAXES","__typename":"PriceItem"}],"pricingRequest":true,"totalPrice":"$0.00"'

str_match_all(string,'"total":\\{"amount":(\\d{3,})')[[1]][2,2]
```

In case no match is found, I would simply like to return `NA`. However, the code above throws an error when a second match is not found. How can I handle nonmatches in this case?

Example:

```
string <- '"basePriceFormatted":"$2,349.00","priceItems":[{"localizedTitle":"7 items","Explanation":null,"total":{"amount":6443,"amountFormatted":"$6,443","currency":"USD","__typename":"PriceTotal"},"type":"GROCERIES","__typename":"PriceItem"}'

str_match_all(string,'"total":\\{"amount":(\\d{3,})')[[1]][2,2]
```

Returns

```
Error in str_match_all(string, "\"total\":\\{\"amount\":(\\d{3,})")[[1]][2,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `purrr::possibly`, which I think is well suited to a situation where you presumably have many such strings. This is an approach that handles the error when it happens. Basically we make a safe version of the indexing step `[2, 2]` which returns `NA` if there is an error, and then we can `map` this function across the matches for each string.

```r
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

strings <- c(
  '"priceItems":[{"localizedTitle":"Fees","localizedExplanation":"Misc fee.","total":{"amount":3198,"amountFormatted":"$3,198","currency":"USD","__typename":"PriceTotal"},"type":"VILLA_FEE","__typename":"PriceItem"},{"localizedTitle":"Occupancy taxes and fees","localizedExplanation":"Tax","total":{"amount":8246,"amountFormatted":"$8,246","currency":"USD","__typename":"PriceTotal"},"type":"TAXES","__typename":"PriceItem"}],"pricingRequest":true,"totalPrice":"$0.00"',
  '"basePriceFormatted":"$2,349.00","priceItems":[{"localizedTitle":"7 items","Explanation":null,"total":{"amount":6443,"amountFormatted":"$6,443","currency":"USD","__typename":"PriceTotal"},"type":"GROCERIES","__typename":"PriceItem"}'
)

safe_second_match <- possibly(~ .x[2, 2], otherwise = NA)

strings %>%
  str_match_all('"total":\\{"amount":(\\d{3,})') %>%
  map_chr(safe_second_match)
#> [1] "8246" NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_extract_all` to extract all the numbers which satisfy the pattern

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text,'(?<="total":\\{"amount":)\\d{3,}')

#[[1]]
#[1] "3198" "8246"

#[[2]]
#[1] "6443"
```

and then use `sapply` to get the second match from each

```
sapply(str_extract_all(text,'(?<="total":\\{"amount":)\\d{3,}'), `[`, 2)
#[1] "8246" NA
```

---

The same can also be done using base R `regmatches` and `gregexpr`

```
sapply(regmatches(text, gregexpr('(?<="total":\\{"amount":)\\d{3,}', 
       text, perl = TRUE)), `[`, 2)
```

**data**

```
text <- c("\"priceItems\":[{\"localizedTitle\":\"Fees\",\"localizedExplanation\":\"Misc fee.\",\"total\":{\"amount\":3198,\"amountFormatted\":\"$3,198\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"__typename\":\"PriceTotal\"},\"type\":\"VILLA_FEE\",\"__typename\":\"PriceItem\"},{\"localizedTitle\":\"Occupancy taxes and fees\",\"localizedExplanation\":\"Tax\",\"total\":{\"amount\":8246,\"amountFormatted\":\"$8,246\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"__typename\":\"PriceTotal\"},\"type\":\"TAXES\",\"__typename\":\"PriceItem\"}],\"pricingRequest\":true,\"totalPrice\":\"$0.00\"", 
"\"basePriceFormatted\":\"$2,349.00\",\"priceItems\":[{\"localizedTitle\":\"7 items\",\"Explanation\":null,\"total\":{\"amount\":6443,\"amountFormatted\":\"$6,443\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"__typename\":\"PriceTotal\"},\"type\":\"GROCERIES\",\"__typename\":\"PriceItem\"}")
```